# How do I cast a base class pointer to a pointer of a class derived from it? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I pass 2 pointers of (class A) to it's derived class (class B) via parameter.

One of the pointers needs to be of class B so that I can call methods that were declared in B.

How would I do that?

Doesn't a static cast only let you do it the opposite way? (B to be dynamically casted to type A). I've been told not to do c-style casts. And reinterpret casts can be dangerous?

The only other one that I can think of is a static cast. Is that what I would need here?

Thanks

Comment: "One of the pointers needs to be of class B so that I can call methods that were declared in B.

How would I do that?" You wouldn't. You'd use [tag:polymorphism].

Comment: If it's virtual you don't need a cast. Otherwise, `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` should work.

Comment: @Johnsyweb hmm can you explain that? I can't find a simple explanation. They all seem to go into pretty great detail.

Comment: Polymorphism is fundamental to understanding object-oriented programming in C++. A brief explanation in the comments would not suffice. I recommend reading [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/78845).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you want to avoid situations like that by using only the member functions declared `virtual` in the base. If you must cast a pointer to a derived class, make sure that the base class has at least one `virtual` function (any function or a destructor would be enough), and then use `dynamic_cast<T>`:

```
BaseClass *bp = new DerivedClass();
...
DerivedClass *dp = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(bp);
if (!dp) {
    cerr << "Not a derived class!" << endl;
}
```

If `bp` points to a `DerivedClass`, dynamic cast succeeds; otherwise, it fails, and returns a null pointer.

You may need to compile with special flags to enable RTTI support.

Comment: Ok. Yeah I have multiple virtual. I'll probably post a new question here in a bit that explains my actual problem. With code and such. Thanks

Comment: You're not limited to just dynamic_cast though, as @Mikael Persson 's answer shows.  Though I do like that you mention possibly needing to enable RTTI, which he does not mention.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` for this purpose. The difference between the two is that `dynamic_cast` will check, at run-time, whether the pointer actually points to an object of the derived class (this requires that there is at least one `virtual` member function (incl. the destructor) in the base class). If you can be sure that the cast is possible, then `static_cast` will just do it without a run-time check.

The syntax is:

```
B* p_b = static_cast< B* >( p_a );

// or:

B* p_b = dynamic_cast< B* >( p_a );
```